# AudioKit Real Time Pitch Correction / Auto Tune

Tags: audiokit

Is it possible to do real time pitch correction to get an autotune like effect with the microphone? If so can someone post an example or maybe we can add an example to the repo?

Do these links possibly help?

https://github.com/michaeldonovan/AutoTalent

http://blogs.zynaptiq.com/bernsee/repo/smbPitchShift.cpp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can use AudioKit's AKFrequencyTracker to get pitch detection of the incoming note, and then use the difference from the closest acceptable scale frequency to drive AKPitchShifter or AKTimePitch to scale the output frequency accordingly. This would be a quick and dirty way to do it, and the results would not compare well to algorithms that are dedicated to this particular effect.

There are no plans to make an example project that does this task, however if you want to contribute code that you write as open-source, we'd consider adding it to our examples.

Comment: Thanks! I just got this working. I didn't realize AKPitchShifter wasn't just an AUTimePitch wrapper. Makes a huge difference with latency thanks so much! My code is super messy right now but i'll clean it up and post it here later and try to make an example project out of it as well

Comment: Is this code available yet I can use it in a project that I am working on?

Comment: @AureliusProchazka Hi, can you expand on this a bit more? I tried different combinations of both of them but results sounded like a chipmunk, way too robotic, and not smooth: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73272366/4833705