# AudiKit AKPitchShifter & AKTimePitch Pitch Correction

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm trying to get an autotune like sound from AKPitchShifter but the most I get is chipmunk type sound. I've played with different combinations with the `AKTimePitch.pitch` and the `AKPitchShifter.shift` both individually and together but everything comes out squeaky and too robotic.

I'm new to this library. Is there anything that I can add, such as other AudioKit classes, to get the sound close to autotune.

```
do {
        
    let file = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "someones-voice.wav")
        
    let player = try AKAudioPlayer(file: file)
    player.looping = true
        
    let timePitch = AKTimePitch(player)
    timePitch.pitch = 0.5
    AKManager.output = timePitch
        
    let pitchShifter = AKPitchShifter(player)
    pitchShifter.shift = 1.5
    AKManager.output = pitchShifter
        
    try AKManager.start()
        
    player.play()
        
} catch {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Update to AK5 and provide a link to a github project and I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka Hi, I finally got the project working correctly with AudioKit v5. Here is the GitHub link: https://github.com/lsamaria/AutoTuneSampler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in git through a pull request addressing a few errors: https://github.com/lsamaria/AutoTuneSampler/pull/3